# Reduce data size of a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In one of table, there are around 900 thousand records. when we checked the data size it is around 800 MB. Can we reduce the data size with out deleting data.

Thanks In Advance.

---

```
CREATE TABLE snmptraps(
 SiteID int(11) NOT NULL default 1,
 SystemID int(11) NOT NULL,
 EnterpriseID varchar(255) default NULL,
 IPAddress varchar(255) default NULL,
 GenericTrap varchar(255) default NULL,
 SpecificTrap varchar(255) default NULL,
 TimestampGen varchar(255) default NULL,
 TimestampRec datetime default NULL,
 OID varchar(1024) default NULL,
 OIDValue varchar(1024) default NULL,
 TimePeriod TIMESTAMP NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PDUType int(11),
 Description varchar(255) default NULL,
);
```

Comment: You could `OPTIMIZE` the table, that *could* free up some space.

Answer (score 8):

try

```
optimize table your_table;
```

> After doing substantial insert, update, or delete operations on an InnoDB table that has its own .ibd file because it was created with the innodb_file_per_table option enabled. The table and indexes are reorganized, and disk space can be reclaimed for use by the operating system.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: Thanks for ur Reply. I had done this, but still table backup is giving same size.

Comment: good answer!  I delete most of the rows in my table, and then run this command, now table size is much smaller !

Comment: For some reason, running this command actually *increases* the file size of my database tables by 10-20%, and I've yet to find a single explanation why.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PROCEDURE ANALYSE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/procedure-analyse.html) to get suggestions about possible optimisations in datatypes. Just be aware, these are just automatic suggestions, and you still should use your own judgement, basing on your application needs.

Also: is that MyISAM or InnoDB? What's the structure of the table?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I am using InnoDB engine.
My table structure is 
CREATE TABLE snmptraps(
  SiteID int(11) NOT NULL default 1,SystemID int(11) NOT NULL,
  EnterpriseID varchar(255) default NULL,
  IPAddress varchar(255) default NULL,
  GenericTrap varchar(255) default NULL,
  SpecificTrap varchar(255) default NULL,
  TimestampGen varchar(255) default NULL,
  TimestampRec datetime default NULL,
  OID varchar(1024) default NULL,
  OIDValue varchar(1024) default NULL,
  TimePeriod TIMESTAMP NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PDUType int(11),
  Description varchar(255) default NULL,
);

Comment: Came across this before but couldn't remember it, after trying `CHECK/ANALYZE/OPTIMIZE TABLE` to no avail. Thank you.

Comment: PROCEDURE ANALYSE() doesn't work in phpmyadmin - is there an alternative for phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the size of your indices (esp: char/varchar/text columns).

Also: If you are using innodb and you use a default setup, the data file (e.g. ibdata1) can only grow - even if you drop tables.

May want to look into the innodb_file_per_table option: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. As u suggested need to re-look on the indices. But this a new dump of that table. I did not drop and add entries into that table.
In this table there is no indexing, if we add indexing will the size gets reduced..?

Comment: When you add an index, size will increase....except, if you do not have a primary key, I believe that you can decrease the size, because a large hidden primary key is generated, if none exists.

Answer (score 0):

If your use-case allows that you may consider the MySQL archive storage engine. This will certainly free a lot of space. But this depends on the usage of your table.

Removing unnecessary indices, rechecking column types, etc may also help. But again this is bound to the needs of your application(s).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few steps which I have followed for my database and I get better performance.

Design your tables to minimize their space on the disk. This can result in huge improvements by reducing the amount of data written to and read from disk.

Table Columns
Row Format
Indexes

Here are the all [details for all the options](http://www.technologiespost.com/2015/06/how-to-optimize-mysql-table-size.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can minimize the output to be easier to copy from host to another one

```
host:~ $ mysqldump -uroot -p database snmptraps | gzip > snmptraps.sql.gz
```